# Magento2-How add multiple tabs in customer edit page and listing there in grid?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

[image]

Magento2-How add multiple tabs in customer edit page  and listing there in grid

Comment: But the above image is Magento 1 customer dashboard example.@Rutvee Sojitra

Comment: Yes, but i want similar functionality in magento2 using ui component

Comment: Actually i want to create using ui-component not using block thanks